# How to generate link based on selected list item?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, search, content-editor-web-part, keyword

I have a Knowledge Base template site that I'm trying to customize. I want to create a simple search site, with just two items on it:
- a dropdown menu which displays content of "Keywords" list (from the same site, using the list as its Data Source)
- a "Search" button, that will redirect me to the address:

```
http://server/site/_layouts/searchresults.aspx?k=[SelectedItem]
```

so that I can easily search by keywords.

I'm used to basic C#, so I was counting on something like `"...search.aspx?k=" + dropdownList.SelectedItem.ToString()`, but from what I found out it's not going to be that easy.

Somebody told me this can be done using "Content Editor" webpart, but I have no idea how to start.

Is there any way to do it, preferably without involving Visual Studio? I'm kind of used to Sharepoint Designer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using SharePoint designer you can create an `HTML Button` in the page and on the `onClick` event execute a `JavaScript` function that builds the URL by concatenating the site URL and the value of the dropdown menu (Get it using getElementById() and access it's value). Then you can use `window.location.href = url` to redirect to another page.

**Example:**

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
 function redirectToSearchPage()
  {
    var dropDown = document.getElementById('dropDownClientId');
    var itemText  = dropDown.options[dropDown.selectedIndex].text;
    window.location.href = "http://server/site/_layouts/searchresults.aspx?k=" + itemText;
  }
</script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">

    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="ddlKey" DataValueField="Title" DataTextField="Title" DataSourceID="spdatasource1" Width="165px"></asp:DropDownList>
    <input name="Button2" type="button" value="Search HTML" onclick="redirectToSearchPage()" />

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Hi Moussa, thanks for the reply. Right now I'm trying to familiarize myself with basic JavaScript and get this selected value as string. It's not going well... Tried `alert(document.getElementById("ddlKey"));` and `alert(document.getElementById('<%= ddlKey.ClientID %>'));`, as suggested on some sites, but I keep getting a `null` object. Could you help me some more? :)

Comment: Ok. Can you post the code you used for creating the dropdown?

Comment: <asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="ddlKey" DataValueField="Title" DataTextField="Title" DataSourceID="spdatasource1" Width="165px"></asp:DropDownList>

Comment: Try adding ClientIDMode="Static" to the dropdown and use document.getElementById("ddlKey").

Comment: `alert(document.getElementById("ddlKey"));` still shows "null".

Comment: Where are you writing your code?

Comment: Inside "onClick" event in button properties. Ends up like this: `<input name="Button2" type="button" value="Search HTML" onclick="alert(document.getElementById(&quot;ddlKey&quot;));" />`

Comment: I mean in a ShrePoint page? In PlaceHolderMain?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Try this: document.getElementById('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ddlKey').

Comment: Still `null`...

Comment: Ok the final solution is to browse to the SharePoint page and view the html source. locate the ddlKey dropdown and get its id. Use this id in JavaScript.

Comment: Yes! Now I get "[object HTMLSelectElement]"! :) Googling for "selectedValue.ToString()" equivalent right now ;)

Answer (score 0):

Final solution, thanks to Moussa: onClick event:

```
var id = 'ctl00_m_g_f9ae17e4_a205_4c1c_88c1_300f89d385b3_ddlKey';
window.location = "http://server/site/_layouts/searchresults.aspx?k=" 
    + document.getElementById(id).options[document.getElementById(id).selectedIndex].text;`
```

All in one line. Element ID od `ddlKey` dropdown found in the webpage source.

Comment: I have added an example that can help you better organize your code.

Comment: Nice, thanks. I thought I need to make it into one line. :)